# Same date but different days with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why does this code give 2 different days :

```js
var m1 = moment("2103-12-18T10:11:00");
var m2 = moment("2013-12-18T15:07:00");
document.write(m1.format('dddd DD/MM/YYYY [at] HH[:]mm'));
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(m2.format('dddd DD/MM/YYYY [at] HH[:]mm'));
```

Output :

```
Tuesday 18/12/2103 at 10:11 
Wednesday 18/12/2013 at 15:07
```

In fact `Tuesday` should be `Wednesday`... My timezone is UTC+1, so it shouldn't be a timezone problem. Is this a bug ?

Comment: first year is 2103 is that what you want?

Comment: @gtgaxiola : not at all. My database was wrong :) Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layer 8 error I think:

```
var m1 = moment("2103-12-18T10:11:00");
var m2 = moment("2013-12-18T15:07:00");
```

**m1** is in the year 2103

**m2** is in the year 2013

Comment: Layer 8 errors are the most difficult to find, especially if you are this layer :)

Comment: Happens to all of us! :P